# VSCode git integration is just awful- is there a better way?

Tags: python, github, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I am a software architect with 23 years commercial experience in C++/C#/Python/Cython. I was forced into using VSCode rather than PyCharm becasue I had to debug some particularly tricky Django templates. I use several machines, one of which is a production test machine. I changed 1 line of code while logged on there and pushed it because it was critical. Now my Git is totally screwed. I have have worked with sourcesafe and clearcase over the years, and I do not have a problem with Git however VSCode has rendered my setup useless.

I now have to save log data on my production test box, wipe the prod folder and reinstall all the code from scratch from Git. This is about a day's work and should not be necessary.

I was warming to VSCode but I will change the way I work until VSCode/Git integration is improved enormously. I will code using VSCode but at any point I want to pull, push, fetch or merge, I will switch to the community edition of PyCharm. PyCharm handles source control like a dream but I don't want to do my day-to-day development with it.

Anybody else out there having similar problems? I simply don't have the time to write a VSCode extension to handle Git properly. I have an end-of-Septemebr deadline and I simply can't have this happen again.

Any feedback is most welcome.

/Luke

Comment: why not use git from the command line?

Comment: Use a git flow structure of your branches and handle it either through CLI, or a gui like sourcetree or smartgit

Comment: This question would be better if it explained what symptom was observed, rather than "Git is totally screwed".

Comment: I have no problems. Perhaps you need to change your workflow as @Artog mentioned? That way you can easily discard or reject that one change that broke everything. Or am I not understanding what the result of your one line change was?

Comment: Specifically, what does "totally screwed" mean?

Comment: Jesus, I don't need this. I have used stackoverflow over the years and have contributed back into it over the years under various user names.

Comment: The answer to the issue is to look at the bash/terminal output generated by VSCode or PyCharm and what is suggested in Git docs. VSCode has an extra argument that PyCharm doesn't have that causes a problem with multiple accounts. Check it out for yourself if you are interested or worth your salt. Don't have ago at me .....

Comment: @MS - perhaps you need to change 'your' workflow. I bet mine is OO and tested to default. There is nothing wrong with the workflow. This issue is done and dusted - I have emailed a guy inside VSC.

Comment: Use command line like it's 1980 or use IntelliJ. If you want, you can still code in VSCode, but just open the project in IntelliJ for the far superior Git integration

Comment: Sorry, I just read your message in more detail and that's what you're doing (sub PyCharm for IntelliJ). I agree though... VSCode's Git absolutely blows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, I just use command line git integration.
However, for large projects or for particularly tricky merge conflicts or other problems, you could use third party git clients such as [Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (what I use) or [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/). These offer a host of features with nice interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have looked at those and they look pretty cool. However I think I have decided what to do. I work on 4 boxes : windows dev, linux dev, test prod (either linux or windows), prod (definitely linux). I would say that my level of Git understanding is pretty good and I use the command line too but when you are coding, and for me that is in C++, compiled into Cythonized Python, then into Django I just want the source control to be easy. I am going to just use the Git command line and will learn more to be really confident. Many thanks - that really helps -  command line it is ...

Comment: I have checked this out some more. VSCode adds various arguments to the command line. There is a bug in the arguments that VSCode adds to simple pull, push, fetch and merge commands. Maybe somebody can fix this. I can't do it until October but I will have a go then if somebody hasn't already done it.

Comment: Right I have emailed a senior guy within "https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues". I don't have time to sign-up and log the issue properly at the moment. There is a bug in the command line arguments added by VSCode to git api usage, I have raised it and will help to fix it, when I have some time. I think VSCode is absolutely great and I am willing to contribute to it. I would consider this closed now. Many thanks guys.

Comment: Just in case I never get a chance help fix this, the bug is to do with the footprint of git code stored by different users. I use git on this project with 2 different accounts : mainly a dev account but also an admin account so I can force changes in junior developer code. The git linked from the test and dev boxes is the admin account. But I am obviously the same person right? So it is not a git problem, it is a VSCode bug.